# Central limit theorem : game of chance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

We consider the following game of chance with independent rounds:

In each round we can win ten euros with probability $0.1$, we can lose one euro with probability $0.7$ and two euros with probability $0.2$. A bet of 50 cents must be paid per round.

Calculate approximately the probability using the central limit theorem for the fact that the profit (= income - outcome) after 100 played rounds is at most five euros. Explain.

From the central limit theorem we have that $$P\left (Z_{100}\leq 5 \right )=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^5e^{-x^2/2}\, dx$$ with $Z_{100}=\sqrt{n}\left (\frac{\overline{X}_{100}-\mu}{\sigma}\right )$ or not?

Comment: How is your definition of $Z_{100}$ the "profit after 100 played rounds"?

Comment: The profit is defined as $0.1\cdot 10-0.7\cdot 1-0.2\cdot 2-0.50$, isn't it? @Golden_Ratio

Comment: Right, but the profit after 100 rounds should simply be a sum of profits from each round; you have it as a z statistic.

Comment: I'll write my answer

Comment: @MaryStar No, that's the expected value of the profit. The actual profit is a random variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll call $X_i$ profit from round $i$, which has moments
$$E[X_i]=-0.5+10(0.1)-1(0.7)-2(0.2)=:\mu\\
\text{Var}(X_i)=E[X_i^2]-(E[X_i])^2=10^2(0.1)+(-1)^2(0.7)+(-2)^2(0.2)-\mu^2=:\sigma^2.$$

Since the $X_i$ are independent, CLT tells us
$$ \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i -\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n}\overset{d}{\rightarrow}N(0,1),$$

which gives an asymptotic approximation for the probability that the profit after 100 rounds is $\leq5$:

$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i\leq 5\right)=P\left(\frac{\frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i -\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt {100}}\leq \frac{\frac{5}{100}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt {100}}\right)\approx \Phi \left(\frac{\frac{5}{100}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt {100}}\right)=\Phi \left(\frac{0.5-10\mu}{\sigma}\right),$$
where $\Phi$ is the CDF of a standard normal.

Comment: What does the $d$ over the arrow mean?

Comment: @MaryStar It means convergence in distribution:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution

Comment: I see!! Thank you very much for your answer!! :-)